# slickgrid : how to know which rows are dirty

Tags: rows, slickgrid

The slickgrid is pretty good!
In disconnected mode, the user makes some changes.
when the job is done the changes are to be saved on the server.
I would like to know if there is a convenient way to update the database.
the dataview contains the up-to-date data, is it aware of the changes that occurred since the loading (e.g. the deleted rows) or do we need to track on ourself the changes?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the onCellChanged event or a custom editCommandHandler to mark rows as dirty and just make an Ajax call to update those rows.  All of the more sophisticated synchronization is up to you - SlickGrid doesn't have any helpers for that.

Answer (score 0):

I had no problem using onCellChanged event when possible.
Now I try to use onSelectedRowsChanged event to get the rowid of the row to be deleted.

But, the grid.getSelectedRows() only returns the row number on the current page.
So I have a problem to get the rowid when the grid is filtered or doesn't display the first page.

I guess there is some dataset that manages the current view but I can't find it.

So what is the best solution to retrieve the rowid from row number according to the current view ?
regards

---

**Update:**
I finally changed my mind by creating a function in grid.js that returns the rowid of the last selected row (not an array to allow only one row deletion)

```
  "getSelectedRowID":     getSelectedRowID,
```

that I use like this :

-> get the current row id

```
grid.onSelectedRowsChanged = function (e, args) {
    currentID = grid.getSelectedRowID();
    .....
    }
```

-> and delete this row if the delete key is pressed

```
grid.onKeyDown = function (e) {
      // delete key
      if (e.keyCode == 46) {
      if (confirm('confirmez-vous la suppression de la ligne : ' + currentID)) {
                dataView.deleteItem(currentID);
                deletedRowIds.push(currentID);
          }
          return true;
      }
   ....
```